# How to by pass or not call a method, invoked inside of another method

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am having a class:

```
class A
{
    public void methodA()
    {
        new B().methodB("string");
        ----
        ----
    }
}


class B
{
    public void methodB(String s)
    {
        ---
        ---
    }
}
```

I need to write a mock, so that I can bypass call to methodB(), inside class A's methodA().

I tried doing:

```
//B b = PowerMockito.spy(new B());
//PowerMockito.doNothing().when(b).methodB(null);
```

---

Also tried spying:

```
//B b = Mockito.spy(new B());
//Mockito.doNothing().when(b).methodB("dummy");
```

But nothing working, and the methodB(), is getting invoked in my unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to intercept all calls to `B.methodB()` and choose whether or not to forward the call to the method.

Comment: Thanks Jason, for the response
I am using junit and PowerMockito for the unit test cases, can it be done with the help of that

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use the *inversion of control* principle to pass the instance of `B` to either `methodA` or the constructor of class `A`. (If you want, you could also have a default constructor `A() { this(new B()); }`.) This will allow you to cleanly pass in a different instance (e.g., a mock) when desired and is a major technique for keeping coupling under control in programs of significant size.

Comment: I thought so, but this is an old code, and modification needs a lot of change, so wanted to write test case without any modifications.

Comment: @YashBansal Then the best initial approach is to add a constructor that accepts a `B` and change the current constructor to a chained `this(new B())` call. Write your tests to the new constructor, deprecate the old one, and migrate your client code gradually.